# Firebase, Parse-Server ou "na unha"

Tags: android, firebase, parse.com

Eu tenho um projeto de escola e minha equipe vai usar a solução mobile com um lado backend, no backend temos um problema, se vamos "fazer" e configurar tudo, que é configurar e criar um banco de dados, criar um Web Service, criar algo Para facilitar a comunicação com o banco de dados. Independente da opção teremos que fazer a parte do Android também.

O cenário é:

-> Projeto de Escola

-> Tempo curto (2-3 meses)

-> Decidimos para uma aplicação simples, mas a solução terá acesso ao banco de dados do smartphone do usuário;

-> Como temos pouco tempo para fazer isso, eu estava falando se vale a pena fazer isso de maneira difícil. Eu sei que tem alguns frameworks que tornam isso mais fácil, mas não é como Firebase ou Back4App que você programa pouco o backend.

A questão é:

Com estas 3 opções Firebase, Back4App e "Hard way", qual é o melhor?

ENTEDAM: Não é uma pergunta sobre o que é bom ou ruim em qualquer situação, eu preciso de algo que melhor se encaixe **nessa** situação

Comment: Eu uso o Firebase e é bastante simples e tem uma documentação bem clara. Sem contar que a comunidade do firebase é activa e gostam de ajudar... Se alguem da sua equipe tiver experiência criando o db, web service, e conectando a db ao aplicativo Android, talvez seja mais rápido do que fazer eles aprenderem o Firebase.

Comment: Obrigado cara, eu expliquei melhor acho que esta mais fácil pra compreender